# Building repositories for relational tables

Tags: entity-framework-4, ddd-repositories

I have a db schema for a fitness application which includes some of the following relational tables - Customer, Session, Workout. Cust to Sess is 1 to many, Sess to workout is 1 to Many. When buidling by repositorys in EF 4, should I create just the one? As each table is related and so I can expose the data of all tables in a single query. Or alternatively would each table warrent it's own repository?

More information: A _customer creates a _session, a _session is associated with a _workout. a _workout keeps track of each set, the weight of that set, the amount of reps and the bodypart worked. Each _session will have multiple workouts associated with it. Like wise, each _customer will have mulitple _sessionId. It would seem that _customer is the aggregate root, and all other information is retrievable through that. So would I have one repository called customer that does everything. What about senarios where we just want the customer but arn't interested in workout etc, will that all be dragged back when calling a customer? Hope this makes sense?

Many thanks

Stu

Answer (score 1):

You're asking about the idea of an "aggregate root." The idea is best documented in Eric Evans' *Domain Driven Design*, but Googling that term will give you enough to get the general idea.

Comment: Yes. I've done some reading around this, although I'm finding it a bit tricky to implement. The solution I'm thinking of implementing is have Session the aggregate and Cutomer the aggregate root. Then have Workout as a seperate aggregate. So a customer repository, and a workout repository. The workout would get the SessionId from the Customer repository.